# DGrid Selection/selectionMode Not Working in AccordionContainer

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am using a custom dgrid w/Selection, DijitRegistry and Pagination that I add to a ContainerPane in an AccordionContainer (dojo 1.9), code below. Data populates properly, and I have set the idProperty of the store I use to a unique identifier (numerical id's). However, I cannot select a row in my grid; it seems the entire grid area beneath the headers gets selected. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
    registry.byId("calAccordion").addChild(new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        id: "allCalPane",
        title: "All Calendars"
    }), "first");
    var CustomGrid = declare([Grid, Selection, DijitRegistry, Pagination]);
    var grid = new CustomGrid({
        store: calStore,
        id: "allCalGrid",
        columns: {
            last: "Last Name",
            first: "First Name"
        },
        selectionMode: "single"
    });
    registry.byId("allCalPane").addChild(grid); 
    grid.on("dgrid-select", function(event) {
        console.log(event.rows[0].data);
    });     
    registry.byId("calAccordion").selectChild(registry.byId("allCalPane"), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you break it out into a simple but complete runnable example for me to test on my system? I'm currently putting a dgrid into a SplitContainer without issue, so I'm up to speed on what you are trying to do.